# Чтение .txt файла OLEDB

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
   public static void ReadTxt(string folderPath)
    {
       string oledbProviderString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited; IMEX=1\"";
        using (OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(oledbProviderString, folderPath)))
        {
            string sqlStatement = "Select * from [debts.txt]";
            //open the connection
            oledbConnection.Open();
            //Create an OleDbDataAdapter for our connection
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStatement, oledbConnection);
            //Create a DataTable and fill it with data
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            //close the connection
            oledbConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

При чтении текстового файла содержащий поле 0303041 на выходе сьедает ноль и возвращает 303041.Как побороть данную проблему.

Comment: Если это целое число, то разницы нет; если - строка, то читайте и получайте эти данные как строковые. Покажите код, который "возвращает 303041".

Comment: Каким образом в OleDbDataAdapter можно задать тип считываемого поля в файле?@Igor

Comment: @Igor - Код который возвращает 303041
 стандартный метод GetValues

while (parser.Reader.Read())
                {
                    object[] values = new object[fields.Count];
                    parser.Reader.GetValues(values);
                    table.Insert(ConvertValues(values, fields, true));
                }

Comment: @Igor нужна именно строка на выходе, но почему то преобразование происходит.

Comment: Драйверу нужна дополнительная информация о типах полей: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Igor без схемы никак?

Comment: Можно экспериментировать с https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-txtreader-for-text-files/